# Using touchscreens with Paintshop Pro

Tags: corel-paint-shop-pro

Does Paintshop Pro [any version] work with a touchscreen [monitor or laptop]?

Using the pen, can I draw, etc. on the screen in Paintshop Pro?

Comment: Have you an touch screen? Laptop, tablet? Please add more infos and welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding touchscreens, are you referring to a tablet/laptop/touchscreen running  Windows 8, or some other platform? If the device and the version of Paintshop Pro both support the ***WinTab API*** then you should be in luck.

I, personally, don't like Windows 8, nor do I wish to promote it (it is just my personal bias), but Paintshop Pro x6 or 7 will work with the Windows 8 touchscreen. Quoting from [PaintShop Pro X6: Best PC Photo Editor](http://www.thephotofinishes.com/picthat/paintshop-pro-x6-best-pc-photo-editor/)

> The new OS  matches smartphones and tablets  not only with touchscreen
>   operations but also with PC ultrabooks and convertible laptops  which
>   deliver better on board still cameras,  light portability plus
>   long-battery life for picture taking and picture processing on the go.
>   But even more important to Corel PaintShop Pro X6 is the fact that
>   Windows 8 supports the best set of touch screen operations and
>   devices. Windows 8 supercharges painting and photo editing not just in
>   PaintShop Pro X6 but most other applications.

You might also want to take a look at this question and answer: [Are graphics tablets worth it?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5/are-graphics-tablets-worth-it)

---

As an aside, Paintshop Pro supports Wacom tablets and the associated "Wacom standard" protocol, and has done for a few years now. From 
[Graphics Tablets: PaintShop Pro](http://www.the-graphics-tablet.com/paint-shop-pro.html)

> In terms of 'bang for your buck', the current version of PaintShop Pro
>   may be the best value on the market and it works perfectly with any
>   one of the Wacom tablets...